# Knowing if a pushed viewController is visible

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, segue

I have an iOS app with this structure

```
SplitViewController
  |  |
  |  |________ TableViewControllerA
  | 
  |________ NavigationController > ViewControllerB > ViewController C
                                         |
                                         |
                                    ViewControllerX
```

As soon as VCB loads, it fires a push segue on its viewWillAppear showing ViewControllerX.

This ViewControllerX is not on the regular flow of the application, it is just a viewController that is shown with the message "select one option", to tell the user to select one option on VCA.

As soon as the user chooses an option on VCA, this VCX has to go away, revealing VCB that is behind.

I have an unwind segue on this VCX to do that, but how do I know if VCX is visible?

How can an action performed on VCA trigger an unwind segue on VCX, so VCX can go away and reveal VCB behind?

I have tried this from VCA but it has no effect

```
  ChooseOption *chooseOption = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chooseOption"];
  [chooseOption performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindChooseOption" sender:nil];
```

choseOption is not nil at this point.

Comment: `chooseOption` may not be nil but it's also not the instance of VCX that you want to have unwind.  (I'm assuming ChooseOption == VCX.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in different ways, and I think it really depends on the context.

Have you tried doing:

```
if(self.navigationController.visibleViewController == self){

}
```

or

```
if([self.navigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[VCX class]]){

}
```

Btw... if VCX is presented modally by the navigationControlller, you can do:

```
if([self.navigationController.presentedViewController && [self.navigationController.presentedViewController isKindOfCLass:[VCX class]]){

}
```

Comment: OK, got that! THANKS!

Comment: Haha great, glad to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at using `NSNotificationCenter`.  When the user does what you want to track in VCA, post a notification.  Have VCX listen for that notification when it has appeared and stop listening when it will disappear.

If VCX gets the notification, it unwinds.  If it's not on the screen, nothing else cares about the notification and it's ignored.